# mongodb $unwind with three nested arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My data has several nested levels:  root --> blocks --> children -->
"array of strings"

I want to use aggregate with $unwind to output some fields from the
"blocks" level and the lowest level, "array of strings".

My question: Based on the data diagram below, what is the code for using aggregate with $unwind to output these fields?

```
Fields from BLOCKS
   block_id
   block_type  
   definition   
All entries from the lowest level array of strings
```

This is different than other postings I've found because I want some levels while skipping others and also because the lower two levels don't have names.

Duplicate rows in the output are not preferred, but I can dedupe at a later stage.

I uploaded an image of the data structure. If you can see the image, there's a blue box surrounding the fields I want.

```
Using "MongoDB Compass", I can see this structure  
ROOT ARRAY
 _id
 edited_on
    -->BLOCKS ARRAY (array of type object)
         block_id
         block_type
         definition
         edit_info (object)
            edited_on
         fields (object)
            display_name
            -->CHILDREN ARRAY (array of type array)
               -->ARRAY (array of type string)
                  0: string
                  1: string
```

The first two arrays have names "blocks" and "children". The last two arrays don't have names.

This may help. I already have a query with $unwind that gives me some fields from the root & blocks levels.

> mongo.exe MyDatabase --quiet --eval "printjson(db.modulestore.structures.aggregate( { $unwind: '$blocks' }, { $project: { _id: 1 , edited_on: 1 , 'definition': '$blocks.definition' , 'block_type': '$blocks.block_type' , 'block_id': '$blocks.block_id' , 'block_edited_on': '$blocks.edit_info.edited_on' , 'display_name': '$blocks.fields.display_name' } } , { $match: { block_type: 'openassessment' } } ).toArray())" > C:\Data\MyOutput.json

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't clear your expectation , I guessed this may be help to you

```
     `db.modulestore.structures.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$blocks"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$fields.children"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 1,
      "edited_on": 1,
      "definition": "$blocks.definition",
      "block_type": "$blocks.block_type",
      "block_id": "$blocks.block_id",
      "block_edited_on": "$blocks.edit_info.edited_on",
      "display_name": "$blocks.fields.display_name"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "block_type": "openassessment"
    }
  }
]` )
```